# Firefox Password script same PW auto login for 1000s devices Possible to use greasemonkey

Tags: firefox, greasemonkey, scripting, autologin

I currently work in a position that i have to manage and access 1000s of pages for troubleshooting and new setup.... and im trying to figure out a way for firefox or chrome to setup ANYtime it sees for instance a a web based page for equipment like (CISCO, Linksys, Sonicwall, T1 controllers)  from the manufacture in the Title bar or from the originating page place a set up 2 - 3 passwords to auto log on with. 1st one of course being the most common so it logs in faster..

I access about 14 different web based products with passwords tied to each of them and if someway i can grab info stating that hey this company is cisco/sonicwall/linksys/hp/ log on with these set of 3-5  credintials. Using possible If then statements....

is that hard i saw some script files but not sure if its difficult because some apps use the MSG BOX built in feature and some use the form submit method built on the page unless i can have 2 different grease monkey scripts at the same time....

thanks.

Comment: I don't understand a word of this. Can you please rephrase what you are trying to do?

Comment: For instance i have a 1000s of web pages 10.xx.xx.xx on our network OR new ones to setup. I need to log into For instance juniper switch and when i try and log in IT comes up with a MSG BOX field. and every time it comes up i have to enter User/ pass.

i want to be able to somehow create a script possibilly greasemonkey.

to when i load the 10.22.11.22 ip in Firefox reads like a title header to determine what im trying to log into (hence it sees Juniper) then USE those 3 sets of credentials.

Comment: sometimes our devices are setup via default passwords or its set with company wide standards hence theres about 2 - 3 passwords (if techs are lazy they dont change it kinda thing)

just trying to make it much easier to troubleshoot issues rather then keep on going to my Pw window pull userID copy and paste then Pull password copy and paste....

SSH
for instance i have a VB script running SecureCRT if i SSH into the device to log in via IF then. it logs in.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track with greasemonkey.  I would find an element on each of the pages which is unique to that page.  The company name seems like an obvious one and use that inside of the script to select which password to use.

Comment: an element as in like tagging somewhere could it be as easy as possible Title bar

but if not ill see whats easier to say what Grep out in a sense.


im not too much of a coder at all is there like a base code i can some how find or get.

thanks

Comment: is there some way to see who i can try and find to code something like this.

Answer (score 1):

If those devices use standard form-based password entry, then there a bunch of Greasemonkey scripts, [like this one](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/750), you can use to start.  A Google search yields plenty more.  ;-)

I'm not sure what you meant by "MSG BOX", but if you meant HTTP authentication (Dialog looks like this:
[image: Basic Auth dialog])

Then Greasemonkey can also help.  See [GreaseMonkey script to auto login using HTTP authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49158/), for example.

However, if memory serves, some of those boxes fire up a JRE and load that from the web page.  The "MSG BOX" may be a dialog from a Java App and Greasemonkey usually can't see such a box.

That's the bad news.  The good news is that most of those boxes have extensive automation interfaces.