# Using ASP.NET Automatically login to an external website and redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

> We have a series of products with
>   built in web servers each of which has
>   a login page, a customer wants to
>   create a web portal in which they log
>   into once, from there they can simply
>   click on any of the devices (external
>   websites) and it will automatically
>   login to that site and redirect them
>   to the page after the login screen.
>   The portal is using ASP.NET MVC, the
>   external devices are Windows CE based
>   units running embedded web servers.
>   Can find a lot on scraping, but not
>   much on redirection after the event.
>   More Info: Apologies for not being
>   detailed enough, External websites
>   using custom authentication, it's a
>   form fill, which then talks to a
>   custom password engine within the
>   device, uses script to detect if the
>   results are good then redirects the
>   the index page from the login page.
>   Basic username and password entered
>   into form, all of which are set to
>   same on all systems, so can be hard
>   coded, customer does not want password
>   on each device but is forced to by the
>   device software. Cookies not being
>   used. Basically the user is presented
>   with a series of links to all the
>   devices (websites essentially) when
>   they click on the link they want to be
>   taken to the main "index" page rather
>   then have to run though the "login"
>   page.

Update : Have successfully managed to navigate target site and login using HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse, so I now have the correct page loaded up in a HttpWebResponse, remaining question is how do I now redirect or open a new browser to display that HttpWebResponse and continue navigating on the logged in target site.

Comment: You didn't provide enough information. What kind of authentication mechanism is used by those external websites? How are clients identified? Are cookies being used? How are the clients going to navigate from the main portal to the external websites. Is there going to be a link or they can enter the address manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [basic authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) this will not be possible. As you've seen you are able to perform an [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) and pass credentials but this is done server side and you cannot continue navigating. The way it works is that the browser needs to set the credential headers used by basic authentication and this can only be done using the login popup. Some flavors of IE might support the following URL: `http://username:password@somesite.com` to provide credentials but not sure would work with other browsers for obvious reasons.

Comment: I understand, server side in "logged in" but no way of passing that control/session to the browser. I will try a JavaScript solution as the user details are not secret, just the login is inconvenient.

Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare script, which create httprequest, try look at 
[GreaseMonkey script to auto login using HTTP authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49158/greasemonkey-script-to-auto-login-using-http-authentication)

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the following using the WPF Web Browser control to auto-login to a site. I found that to be able to navigate the site without the Authorization Header getting lost or removed I had to do the following otherwise for each new page the user was prompted again.  This solution also does not require the user:password@site syntax to be enabled.

```
    private bool _redirected = false;
    private const string BaseUrl = @"http://mySite";

    private void Navigate()
    {
        var helpUrl = BaseUrl;
        var authHeader = GetAuthHeader();

        _docWindow.Browser.Navigate(helpUrl, string.Empty, null, authHeader);           
        _docWindow.Browser.Navigating += Browser_Navigating;

    }

    private string GetAuthHeader()
    {
        byte[] authData = UnicodeEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_userName + ":" + _password);
        string authHeader = "Authorization: Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(authData);
        return authHeader;
    }

    void Browser_Navigating(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
    {            
        if (_redirected)
        {
            _redirected = false;
            return;
        }
        var newPage = BaseUrl + e.Uri.AbsolutePath;

        e.Cancel = true;
        _redirected = true;
        _docWindow.Browser.Navigate(newPage, string.Empty, null, GetAuthHeader());
    }
```