# Is it possible to have php and .htaccess authentication through one form?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am using both PHP and .htaccess login systems on my website.Both authentications are handled seperately(i.e php by quering database and .htaccess by including password file in root directories). PHP login directs user to the specific page and .htaccess login directs user to a specific directory that includes subdirectories and various files. As per current situation if a user wants to access directories he is required to login twice. First login directs him to a page where he finds a link and clicking on the link again prompts him to enter username and password and directs him to the directory.

Is there a way that would simplify the two authentication problem and make it one. I mean the login system should work in such a way whereif user A logs in he will be directed to the page, and if user B logs through the same login he should be directed to the directories?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `PHP_AUTH_USER` and `PHP_AUTH_PW` values in `$_SYSTEM`: http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

Comment: same thinking here... you can then put a .htaccess rewrite rule in effect which will always check into which subfolder user requested access and verify credentials for them that way

Answer (score 1):

You can try to log in using HTTP authentication by setting the "Authorization" HTTP header, with the value of this header set to the string `basic username:password`, but with the `username:password` portion encoded via `base64_encode`. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55744/1935500)

However, this seems like a bad design imo. Are both scripts on the same server, if yes, then they can access the same resources from the backend.

Another option you can do is switch the protection to use php: http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php